# Aumentar tamanho de array multidimensional no tempo de execução

Tags: array, c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, array-multidimensional

**Problema:**

Eu mantenho uma array multidimensional do tipo 2D que possui um tamanho dinâmico, está sempre a crescer, como não estou autorizado a utilizar `vector` preciso desenvolver uma estratégia para poder aumentar o tamanho desta array no tempo de execução.

**Atual estratégia:**

- Criar nova array
- Passar dados da array antiga para nova array
- Apagar array antiga e substituir pela nova

Atualmente estou tendo problema na última fase, me retorna erros estranhos como este:

> malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x108a0b5d8: probably
>   modified after being freed.

**Pergunta:**

Qual é o problema aqui e como resolver?

**Código desenvolvido:**

```
void person::increaseDataSize(const int newSize, int oldSize)
{
    // Allocate new cells
    personInformation * newData[newSize][newSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < newSize; j++)
        {
            newData[i][j] = new personInformation();
        }
    }

    // Fill new cells with old cells data
    for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < oldSize; j++)
        {
            newData[i][j]->data0 = this->data[i][j]->data0;
        }
    }

    // Delete old cells items
    for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < oldSize; j++)
        {
            delete [] this->data[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Fill old cells with new cells
    for(int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < newSize; j++)
        {
            this->data[i][j] = newData[i][j];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer aumentar o tamanho do array (#linhas e #colunas), então o array em si precisa ser alocado dinamicamente. Você não mostrou como `this->data` foi alocado, mas se for igual a como alocou `newData`, então não foi dinamicamente.

A alocação dinâmica de um array 2D é feita conforme o seguinte código.

```
personInformation*** data = new personInformation** [size]; // aloca as linhas
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    data[i] = new personInformation* [size]; // aloca as colunas por linha
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        data[i][j] = new personInformation(); // aloca o objeto
}
```

E a desalocação deverá ser da seguinte forma:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        delete data[i][j]; // libera o objeto
    delete [] data[i]; // libera array coluna
}
delete [] data; // libera array linha
```

A sua alocação de `newData` apresenta um potencial problema. Para alocar um array **estaticamente**, o tamanho deve ser conhecido em **tempo de compilação**. Parâmetros de função não necessariamente são conhecidos em tempo de compilação. Se for o caso, seu programa poderá apresentar **comportamento indefinido**.

Você usa o `delete []` para liberar um objeto simples. Essa forma é para liberar arrays dinâmicos (alocados com `new []`). Para objetos simples use apenas `delete data[i][j]`.

No último laço você usa `newSize` para iterar sobre `this->data` que possui tamanho menor (`oldSize`). Você precisa desalocar todo o array e realocar com o novo tamanho antes de fazer esse laço.

Comment: Obrigado! Mas creio que esse seja só um dos problemas, pois continuo recebendo a mensagem de erro mencionada.

Comment: Editei a resposta e apresentei todos os problemas que encontrei em seu código.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente o que disse, mas estou com dificuldades na realocação, qual a maneira correta de realocar? Posso fazer oldData = data?

Comment: Aloque `newData`, copie os dados para ele, desaloque `this->data` e faça `this->data` apontar para `newData`. Tudo dinamicamente como descrevi acima.